# Xpath com Python - Pegar texto depois de tag em uma div

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

Estou tentando pegar um texto depois de uma tag que está dentro de uma div, em um html. O problema que estou tendo é que não estou recebendo o texto, só uma string vazia. Pesquisei em outros lugares e não vi ninguém com um problema semelhante :/

Aqui vai o código html:

```
<div class="list-view-item-title-wrapper">
    <div class="list-view-item-title-top">
        <div class="list-view-item-type">
            "Webcast"
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/resources/actionable-awareness-unlock-your-influence" class="list-view-item-title">
        <h2>
            "Actionable Awareness: Unlock Your Influence"
        </h2>
    </a>
    <div class="list-view-item-date">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        "September 24, 2020"
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

E o python:

```
def get_posts_elements(self, html):
    posts = self.get_posts(html)

    # - get_posts -> retorna html.xpath("//div[@class='list-view-item-title-wrapper']")
    # - html -> lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get('https://www.scrum.org/resources'))
    
    for post in posts:

            # --- Recebendo com sucesso:
        try:
            self.data['Type'].append(post.xpath(".//div[@class='list-view-item-type']")[0].text.strip())
        except:
            self.data['Type'].append('')

        try:
            self.data['Title'].append(post.xpath(".//a[@class='list-view-item-title']/h2")[0].text.strip())
        except:
            self.data['Type'].append('')
        
        try:
            self.data['Link'].append(urljoin(self.base_url, post.xpath(".//a[@class='list-view-item-title']/@href")[0]))
        except:
            self.data['Link'].append('')


            # --- Recebendo com falha:
        data = post.xpath(".//div[@class='list-view-item-date']")[0].text
        print(data)
```

No caso, quero pegar os textos referentes as datas de cada post, como faço com o título e tipo. No exemplo acima seria "September 24, 2020" mas só recebo uma string vazia.

Meus imports:

```
import lxml.html as parser
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urljoin
```

Comment: Tem que ser com o xpath ?? Já tentou utilizar o BeautifulSoup junto com o Selenium e sempre tenho bons resultados. - [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) - [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)

Comment: Já usei o BeautifulSoup e o Selenium, também tive bons resultados, mas dessa vez preciso usar somente XPath :/

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que consegui resolver usando os conceitos de herança em XPath. Usei

```
post.xpath(".//div[@class='list-view-item-date']/descendant-or-self::*/text()")[1])
```

Ao invés de

```
post.xpath(".//div[@class='list-view-item-date']")[0].text
```

/[descendant-or-self](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)::[*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_wildcard.htm) está, resumidamente, sendo usado para pegar todas as filhas/netas do nó, de forma mais abrangente. Assim consegui finalmente identificar o text. Também precisei mudar o indice, já que o elemento que quero é sempre o segundo da lista.